# Universal App Windows Phone Orientation

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Recently I was developing a Universal app for both the Windows Phone and Windows Store. In that app, I was trying to fix the Orientation of the App to Landscape. But in WinRT based apps of Windows Phone 8.1, I failed to find any Orientation option.

In the Silverlight apps, we can fix the Orientations as we want. But is there any way to fix the Orientation to Landscape mode in the Universal Apps?

It will be very helpful if someone help me in this regard. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you looked in `package.appxmanifest` file - supported rotations?

Comment: Thanks man. This was the thing that I needed. I was trying to set the orientation from the MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs. I have never thought in the way. Thanks again. :D @Romasz

Comment: You might find this interesting http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under WinRT you can have a look at [DisplayInformation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation), where you will find probably all you need.

You can also declare your supported rotations in *Package.appxmanifest* file in <kbd>Supported rotations</kbd>.

[Here you can download](http://1drv.ms/1lTLvd2) an example of an App with three *Pages*, each with different orientation.

Comment: I converted above example to Windows 10 Universal Application. Unfortunatelly locking the orientation is not working on a Toshiba Windows 10 Tablet. Every time we rotate the tablet the UI is auto rotated even though we are declaring support just for portrait It seems that in tablets the orientation lock is not possible. Also I tested same example on a Lumia 550 and orientation was locked. Rotating the mobile did not changed the UI orientation. So we have different behaviour based on the device.

Comment: @ByronGavras I haven't tried that on tablet. Though, if you disable rotation and it still rotates, I would consider this as a bug.