# Where has support for orientation gone in Universal Apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm working on a universal app, and I need for one page within this app to use landscape orientation (for taking a photo), whilst the majority of the app is primarily portrait orientation.

How do I tell the OS and the designer this, as the `SupportedOrientation` and `Orientation` properties from `PhoneApplicationPage` from the Silverlight toolkit, don't appear to exist on [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx)

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24065554/2681948)?

Comment: @Romasz No, because that doesn't answer my question - that appears to be app-wide, as opposed to *just for one page*.

Comment: @RowlandShaw did you try selecting the orientations from the Package Manifest?

Comment: @anonshankar Yes, and in my tests, even with only "Landscape" as a supported orientation, the designer and deployed app still come out in portrait orientation. Additionally, that can *only* target the whole app and not a single page, which is what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a different orientation on the *Page*, then I've been able to make it like this - by setting Page's orientation in its constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
}

public Page1()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
}
```

[Here is simple example](http://1drv.ms/1lTLvd2) with three *Pages* - each with different orientation.